# Angular UI Grid not displaying data

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am  learning Angular and using the UI grid where I populate the grid from a simple loop method in the ShopplingList controller. The grid is displayed with the column headings but the data is not and I have no errors in chrome when I hit F12. Any help on where I am going wrong!!

My HTML and Javascript

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.gridOptions1 = {};

    $scope.gridOptions1.columnDefs = [{
      name: 'ID'
    }, {
      name: 'Shopping Item'
    }];

    $http.get("/ShoppingList/getShoppingItems/")
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
      }).error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }
]);
```

```css
body {} .grid {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>ShoppingList</title>
</head>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Irlca/ShoppingList.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions1" class="grid"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My Model

```
public class ShoppingListModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string shoppingItem { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller
public class ShoppingListController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ShoppingList/
        public ActionResult ShoppingList()
        {
            return View("ShoppingList");
        }

```
    public ActionResult getShoppingItems()
    {
        List<ShoppingListModel> lstRes = new List<ShoppingListModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ShoppingListModel tsk = new ShoppingListModel();
            tsk.id = i * 10;
            tsk.shoppingItem = "Milk" + i.ToString();
            lstRes.Add(tsk);
        }

        return Json(lstRes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an assumption but first... can you debug the `get` function and make sure you get the right response? (a list if items)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `get` method receives the requested entities, there is one thing missing in your `ui-grid` configuration: the entity's `field`. This is set in `columnDefs` property and is in charge of connecting the `name` property (which will be the column header) to the actual entity field.

Try this:

```
$scope.gridOptions1.columnDefs = [{
      name: 'ID',
      field: 'id'
    }, {
      name: 'Shopping Item',
      field: 'shoppingItem'
    }];
```